# Custom FilterSet doesn't filter by two fields at the same time

Tags: django, django-orm, django-filters

I wrote custom FilterSet to filter queryset by two fields but it doesn't work properly when it's filtering on two fields at the same time.

my FilterSet:

```
class EventFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    values = None
    default = None

    category = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=EventCategory.objects.all(),
    )
    interval = filters.CharFilter(
        method='filter_interval'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('category', 'interval')

    def filter_interval(self, queryset, name, value):
        if self.request.query_params.get('current_time'):
            try:
                interval = getattr(self, f'get_{value}_interval')()
                interval = list(map(lambda date: self.to_utc(date), interval))
                return self.queryset.filter(Q(status=Event.STARTED) | (Q(status=Event.NOT_STARTED, start_at__range=interval)))
            except Exception as e:
                pass
        return queryset
```

APIView:

```
class ListEventsAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ListEventsSerializer
    filter_class = EventFilter
    search_fields = 'title',
    filter_backends = filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Event.objects.filter(Q(status=Event.STARTED) | (Q(status=Event.NOT_STARTED) & Q(start_at__gte=date)))
```

Here is generated SQL when I'm trying to filter only by category:

```
SELECT "*" FROM "events" WHERE (("events"."status" = 'started'
OR ("events"."status" = 'not_started' 
AND "events"."start_at" >= '2019-06-19T13:24:26.444183+00:00'::timestamptz)) 
AND "events"."category_id" = 'JNPIZF54n5q')
```

When I'm filtering on both:

```
SELECT "*" FROM "events" WHERE (("events"."status" = 'started' 
OR ("events"."status" = 'not_started' AND "events"."start_at" >= '2019-06-19T13:24:26.444183+00:00'::timestamptz)) 
AND ("events"."status" = 'started' OR ("events"."start_at" BETWEEN '2019-06-19T07:16:48.549000+00:00'::timestamptz AND '2019-06-30T20:59:59.000059+00:00'::timestamptz AND "events"."status" = 'not_started')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
               return self.queryset.filter(Q(status=Event.STARTED) | (Q(status=Event.NOT_STARTED, start_at__range=interval)))
```

You're using queryset from FilterSet class itself. This queryset doesn't have any previous filters applied, so by using it you're cancelling another filter. Just remove `self.` from this line to use queryset that is passed to this function as a parameter and everything will work fine.